Problem CI/CD gitlab.com to Ubuntu server
Recently, I created pipeline for automation of my task from gitlab.com to my VPS server.
I craeted runner on docker and the link is correct in gitlab.
The pipeline run successfully but never image is created on my docker VPS. Can you help? This is code
This is my dockerfile
# Use an official Node.js runtime as a parent image
FROM node:latest

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Build the application
RUN npm run build

# Expose the application port
EXPOSE 3000

# Define the command to run the application
CMD ["npm", "start"]

my .gitlab-ci.yml
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build_job:
  stage: build
  image: node:latest
  script:
    - echo "Removing node_modules..."
    - rm -rf node_modules/  # Remove node_modules directory if it exists
    - echo "Installing dependencies..."
    - npm install
    - echo "Building the application..."
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/

deploy_dev:
  stage: deploy
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - echo "Stopping and removing any existing container..."
    - docker stop demo-front || true
    - docker rm demo-front || true
  script:
    - echo "Deploying to development environment..."
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" "$CI_REGISTRY"
    - docker build -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:dev" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:dev"
    - docker images  # List all Docker images to verify the image is built
    - docker run -d -p 3002:3000 --name demo-front --restart always "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:dev"
  only:
    - dev
  environment:
    name: development
    url: https://demo-web.test.com
  after_script:
    - docker logout "$CI_REGISTRY"


What does "never image is created on my docker VPS" mean?? What do you expect? What commands do you run that doesn't work? Any error?

nothing error after execution and this image demo-front doesnt exist on docker. The command is in file above.

What does "the image doesn't exist on docker" mean? It's not pushed to the registry?

yes, the image doesnt push in registry

Show us the output of the job then? What command are you running to check that? Did you add some echo statements in your job to troubleshoot maybe?

I obtain this error:
Starting to deploy
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p $SSH_PORT $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST "docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY"
Load key "/root/.ssh/id_rsa": error in libcrypto
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
root@ip: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Running after_script

the SSH_PRIVATE_KEY and SSH_PUBLIC key is in gitlab account

You said there was no error.. then there's no SSH in your gitlab-ci, where does that come from? Please update your original post with complete and up to date information.

the problem was, the sshy key isnt convert to base 64
